# If accepted by dpda and npda,then it is regular. Is it correct?

Tags: automata, finite-automata, pushdown-automata

If accepted by dpda and npda,then it is regular. Is it correct?.I had confusion that some where I studied that a regular language is exactly should accepted by finite automata.....

Comment: If a language is regular it will be accepted by some PDA but not vice-versa.

Comment: What is "it"? Are you aware that DPDA and NPDA have different power, and both are more powerful than finite automata? I think you need to read your sources more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

If it's accepted by a DPDA, then clearly it is also accepted by a NPDA with exactly one possible transition for each configuration.

However, there are languages accepted by DPDA's not accepted by any DFA. The canonical example of a non-regular languages $L = \{a^n b^n \mid n \geq 0\}$ is accepted by a DPDA by empty stack (an easy exercise should be to design such a DPDA).

You're right that every finite state automata accepts a language that is regular. However, PDA's are not finite state in the larger sense of state that includes not only the internal state $q_0$, but the contents of the stack. The stack is unbounded in size, hence PDAs are not finite state.

Comment: "every finite state automata accepts exactly the regular languages" -- that sentence is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Raphael Is it possible for an automata with finitely many configurations to accept a non-regular language?

Comment: I guess you wanted to write "every finite state automaton accepts a regular language" with which I wholeheartedly agree.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a regular language, then you can make a push down automata (finite automata as well) for accepting it. Non- deterministic Push down automatas accept Context Free Languages, and regular languages is a subset of context free languages. In other words, "Every regular language is a CFL, but converse is not true."